# Cannot find Symbol method charAt(int)?

Tags: java

I keep recieving this error when I compile the program:

```
error: cannot find symbol

if(letter == charAt(0).getTheword())

symbol:   method charAt(int)
```

The word is an arrayList and letter is a keyboard input. What am I doing wrong and what should be changed?

Comment: where is the string?

Comment: charAt(int) is a method of String. It looks here as if you're calling charAt(0) directly rather than as a String method (i.e. it should be preceded by a String object).

Comment: You should post more code if you want more help...

Answer (score 4):

`charAt` is a method that operates on a String.

So example usage would be:

```
String s = "abc";
System.out.println(s.charAt(0)); //prints out 'a';
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change condition to

```
if(letter == getTheword().charAt(0))
```

ie string should be before the method charAt()

Answer (score 1):

[charAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) is a method that only works on Strings, as described in the documentation. It returns the char at the given index. Let's look at a simple example:

```
String word = "Cow";
char letter = word.charAt(0);
System.out.println(letter);
```

This will print out the letter (char) "C" to the console, since the letter 'C' is at index 0 of the word "Cow".

So the part where you're going wrong is that you're not specifying on which String you want to call the `charAt()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [get](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_get.htm) instead.

[charAt](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_charat.htm) is a method that's suppoused to operate on strings, while you are operating on an arrayList.

In context:

```
if(letter == <your arraylist>.get(0).getTheword())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.... Your not using a string to use charAt

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a character: ");

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

        words.add("Test");

        char ch = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);

        if(ch == words.get(0).charAt(0)){

            System.out.println("Match");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Do not Match");
        }
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You're* not using a string

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to prepend the `charAt()` function with the name of the string variable it is working upon, followed by .(dot) operator.

For example:

```
String st = "Wonderful Life!";

//to find out the 1st character of the given string st.
st.charAt(0);

//to find the 2nd character
st.charAt(1);
```

Note: Indexing starts from 0.